# How can I create tiny pattern-tiles that repeats well in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, tiles

Whenever I have tried making tiny tiles for tiling, like `10px x 10px` in size, the only thing I have ever been able to make well is diagonal lines.

I suppose it has something to do with painting principles like how we perceive tiny light and shadow (up/down,inside/outside).

How can I create tiles that repeat well in Photoshop?

Comment: could you add example images of two kind: a) looking good, and b) fails to look good. it would make the question more clear.

Comment: By small patterns, do you mean a tiny tile with a pattern, such as your avatar? Or do you mean a tiny tile that will be repeated?

Comment: later one i meant

Comment: An example would always help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good is a very subjective description...

I like to make connecting lines so the end result looks woven. I also keep keep colors to a minimum, typically just 2 or 3.

Why don't you start by collecting a few samples that you like, then recreate them with a few small touches of your own?

Comment: nice advice....

Answer (score 0):

"Looks good" is an impossible thing to answer, particularly without images of what you think looks good, and some examples of what you have made that in your eyes fails.

There are a lot of tile generators out there, that might be much simpler than starting from scratch in photoshop. And if you do not directly use the result of these engines, you will get a pretty good idea of how it works structurally.

Here are but a few:

**[Bgpatterns](http://bgpatterns.com/)**

**[Background image generator](http://bg.siteorigin.com/)**

**[Stripe generator](http://www.stripegenerator.com/)**

...and here is a collected list of a [**few different tile generators**](http://singlefunction.com/15-online-background-generators/) of various kinds.